# Display serial incoming data on tkinter scrollbar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, serial-port, pyserial

I downloaded a small arduino program in order for it to produce serial data.
My goal (first iteration) is to create an application that will replace the arduino IDE serial - since i only want to read serial data.

This is how the data looks like on the arduino IDE serial interface.

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import serial.tools.list_ports
from tkinter import scrolledtext 
#new stuff
import time
import serial
import threading
import continuous_threading


#to be used on our canvas
HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

#hardcoded baud rate
baudRate = 9600

#Serial Stuff-----------------------------------------
ser = serial.Serial('COM16', baudRate)
val1 = 0
index = []
def readSerial():
    global val1
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    val1 = ser_bytes
    index.append(val1)
    disp = tk.Label(frame2, text=index[0])
    disp.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 8))
    disp.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.5)

t1 = continuous_threading.PeriodicThread(0.5, readSerial)


# --- main ---
root = tk.Tk() #here we create our tkinter window
root.title("Sensor Interface")

#we use canvas as a placeholder, to get our initial screen size (we have defined HEIGHT and WIDTH)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()


# --- frame 2 ---
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff') #remove color later
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

# make a scrollbar
scrollbar = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame2)
scrollbar.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
# --- frame 2 ---

t1.start()
root.mainloop() #here we run our app
```

I have a frame2 which is a scrollText that i want my data to appear (i also have another frame above it, that i removed it here so that i don't confuse people with unnecessary code).

Ideally i would like the data to appear like in the arduino IDE, with autoscroll - but first i have to walk before i can run.

All the serial "action" happens in the portion i have marked with comments called 'Serial stuff'.

Is my placement code correct?

```
disp = tk.Label(frame2, text=index[0])
disp.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 8))
disp.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.5)
```

I want each line to be placed in a new line in the textbox, like my first picture

EDIT: I followed scotty3685's advice (Thanks a lot sir!) but look at what i get now at my tkinter frame:

[image]

If you compare with the first picture, it's close but it's not really there.

Comment: At the moment you seem to be creating a new label for each line of text. What you probably want to do is insert text in to the scrolled text widget (which is a text box with a scroll bar). Can you confirm that you want the text inside the textbox with the scrollbar rather than a new label created?

Comment: @scotty3785 Yes, i want it inside the textbox with the scrollbar. I am in a good route thanks to your answer, not there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to insert text into a ScrolledText widget is as follows

```
s.insert("end","some_text that I want to insert")
```

- `s` is the name of the scrolledtext widget (in your case this is
  called scrollbar confusingly)
- The first argument to insert `"end"`
  tells the scrolled text widget to place the new text at the end of
  the current text in the textbox.
- and the second argument to insert is
  the text you want to insert (in your case, `val1`).

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for your help! I am getting data inside the textbox now, but it's not exactly what i want. I edited my question and added a picture with what i get now. If you compare with the first picture, some data is the same but there is data missing. I don't understand why my incoming data looks that way. Perhaps an error in the decoding of the serial input?

Comment: Rechecked with the arduino serial. It displays the line 'NO FORMAT' line... Then coutns up to 63, then 'NO FORMAT' line again, in an infinite loop. So i don't understand why pyhton only displays the 'NO FORMAT' line continuously...

Comment: I think you need to change the `index[0]` to `val1` when you write out to the textbox. Edited my answer. With `index[0]` it will only ever print the first line added to the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. At first kinda slow, but then i changed the t1 = continuous_threading.PeriodicThread(0.5, readSerial) from 0.5 to 0.1 and now it's all good. There are a couple of bugs still, when it comes to decoding, but i will search for them.